# How to use a callback in jQuery animate when there are options

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make this working:

```
jQuery('.header').animate({ opacity: 1 }, {queue:false,duration:250},function(){
        console.log('complete');
});
```

but unfortunately callback isn't triggered.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing an object as the second argument, any callback you want to be executed should be included in that object.

```
jQuery('.header').animate({ opacity: 1 }, {
    queue:false,
    duration:250,
    complete: function(){
        console.log('complete');
    }
});
```

You can learn more on how the API works in their [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)